# How do I create calculated column in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to Power BI and was wondering if someone can help me.

I have a table

```
A        B         Status
---------------------------
Asset1       B1       Compliant
Asset1       B2       N/A
Asset2       B1       Non- Compliant
Asset2       B2       Compliant
Asset3       B1       Compliant
Asset3       B2       Compliant
```

I have to find the Asset which are 100% compliant(Count of Asset where status of all the rows of Column B is Compliant and not non Compliant and we need to ignore N/A.

Out put I want

### A    100%Compliant

Asset1      Y
Asset2      N
Asset3      Y

Thanks

Comment: The edit doesn't make sense: What's the status of column B now?

Comment: Any help Power BI experts???

Comment: Please be aware of the rules of engagement. We are doing this for free so a little patience on your side is appriciated..

Comment: Would be nice to confirm you are happy with an answer by acknowledging an answer as answered.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

You can create a measure:

```
IsCompliant = 
VAR NumNonCompliant = CALCULATE(COUNTAX('Table', [B]), 'Table'[Status] = "Non - Compliant")
RETURN IF(NumNonCompliant = 0, "Y", "N")
```

The variable `NumConCompliant` calculates the number of rows with status = "Non - Compliant". Then it is compared with 0 to find any non-compliance.

Then the measure returns the state of "A" in the given context. This gives you the flexibility of assigning compliance measure to a combination of assets. For example if you filter data on "A = Asset1", the result would be "Y", and (A = Asset1 || A = Asset2) results in a "N". (Since the combination of Asset1 & Asset2 are non-compliant).

Refer to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/context-in-dax-formulas-2728fae0-8309-45b6-9d32-1d600440a7ad?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) doc about measures and contexts.

Comment: Have you tested your solution?

Comment: I did after your comment :)
Had some typos and made the corrections. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extra column in your table:

```
100% Cpmpliant = 
var asset = Compliant[A]
var allRows = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Compliant); FILTER(Compliant; Compliant[A] = asset && Compliant[Status] <> "N/A"))
var compliantRows = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Compliant); FILTER(Compliant; Compliant[A] = asset && Compliant[Status] = "Compliant"))
return if (allRows = compliantRows; "Y";"N")
```

This calculates the rows of the asset without the N/A and compares it against teh rowcount of the compliant. If this is equal, they are all compliant-

Next you can create a visual with two columns ass below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aldert...It works perfectly. Can I do the same in Power Query?I would appreciate if you can give any guidance on power Query? I want to Pivot my query and Power Query only have the transform function.

Comment: Thank you @Peter, I hope this user comes to her senses now.